# Spring boot multiple tests with testcontainers

Tags: spring-boot-test, testcontainers, spring-boot-testcontainers

I am trying to use Spring Boot Tests with test containers. I wrote an abstract integration tests that all integration tests are using.

```
@Testcontainers
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@TestConstructor(autowireMode = TestConstructor.AutowireMode.ALL)
abstract class AbstractITest : AbstractTest(){

    companion object{

        @Container
        @ServiceConnection(type = [JdbcConnectionDetails::class])
        val mysql = MySQLContainer("mysql:latest").withInitScript("test.sql")

    }

}
```

When I run every test class individually through intellij, it runs normally.
But when I try to run all tests together, I get connection timeout on the second class executed. When I debug, I notice that my hikari connection pool is configured with a jdbc url of the previous test run. For example, first run uses 33835 port and the second uses 338836, but the hikari connection pool in the second run is configured with the previous 33835 port.
I think I configured everything as shown in the official documentation of spring boot.
Why is this problem occurring?

In logs, i can see a log

```
2023-10-26T19:12:34.718+03:00  INFO 46718 --- [    Test worker] tc.mysql:latest                          : Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:32847/test)
```

but in connection pool, i see port 32846.

I am using spring boot 3.1.4.

Comment: I think all that you need to know about how to use the the same test container in multiple test classes, you can find in `Singleton containers` part of [documentation](https://java.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/)

Comment: @AndreiLisa , Spring's documentation does not mention it, and presents the same example as mine. So i thought maybe the problem is in something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this annotation before your abstarct class definition `@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)`
This will create a service connection details everytime a connection is required beacuse we set proxyBeanMethods to `false`, i.e.: prototype not singleton.

Read about proxyBeanMethods here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html#proxyBeanMethods()